# Calculating the Listview's Each rows height in android (listview in side the scrollview)

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing an application  where i have to show the listview in scrollview and the problem is that i am not getting the proper height of listview i have followed almost all the code from below links.

[Android ListView rows in ScrollView not fully displayed - clipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709411/android-listview-rows-in-scrollview-not-fully-displayed-clipped)

[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#3495908)

But every time i am getting listview like this
[image]

I don't know how should I calculate the height of list I tried no of different ways but due to variable size of each row in list it is not working. If any one knows how it can be calculated it run time in Adapter file or from main activity/fragment let me know how should do it.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Listiview itself has scrollview

Comment: It's not a good idea to put a scrolling view inside another scrolling view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325256/scrollview-only-works-in-listview/35402052#35402052

Comment: go through the above link. its use full to you because I think your problem solution is there

Comment: i have already used this code but still I am facing the above issue. is there any way that i can do it via custom. if possible let me know but I have never made custom control in android.

Comment: It maybe simpler to solve your problem. Why put the `ListView` in a `ScrollView`? What is your end?

Comment: because i have to show the order in listview and below the list i have to show the charges and all other detail so i have to take the scrollview and listview both. i can not show the whole screen here. so you may not get it that how my screen will look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution. Add this line `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(item_Listview);` and the method like below

```
if(item_lists != null && item_lists.size() > 0) {
                itl = new Itemlist(getActivity(), item_lists);
                item_Listview.setAdapter(itl);
                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(item_Listview);
            }



    private void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView item_listview) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = item_listview.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                return;
            }
            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, item_listview);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = item_listview.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight
                    + (item_listview.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            item_listview.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

Comment: not working i tried now and i am having the same type of code from number of links one or more line is added/removed to this method other wise whole code in this method is same almost where ever i searched.

Comment: please help i am working on this issue since 3-4 days

Comment: <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/item_listview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

Comment: i have did same in xml too, but nothing is working for me. i dont know where i am making a mistake.                                                                                         By the way thanks to all for helping me

Comment: hello  Tamil Arasan please accept invitation from Deeplove9493@gmail.com